# Calculating raster weighted centroids for polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, features, centroids

I need to calculate centroids for each feature in a polygon layer, weighted by the values of a raster. So the centroids are shifted towards higher raster values.

I found a way, but it is complicated. Is there an existing tool which can do this?

[image]

Comment: Why not just iterate through each polygon, mask to polygon i, calculate a probability density function  (PDF) and then take the mode. This represent a spatial process in a more relevant way.

Comment: That might work, I will try it

Comment: I have to admit that I have R or Python in mind where a vector of raster values can be modeled and indexed. In this way a pdf can be derived (eg, density, ks), the index of the mode returned along with the corresponding [x,y] coordinates. Not sure how realistic this is in QGIS but, there is likely a way for somebody savvy with the software (which is not me).

Answer (score 5):

I've done similar approaches with vectors to get population based centroids.
I don't know any existing tool that does this but it would be neat.

Here is another approach, it is also complicated but maybe a bit more precise than grid + variable buffer.

It is a vector based approach, basically weighting coordinates by pixel value. If there was a way to create a raster where pixel values were x and y coordinates without point conversion, would be easier.

[image]

And here is the result

[image]